# Convert rows to columns dynamically

Tags: oracle10g, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have table:

`name | surname | project | dates | hours`
`aaa aaaa 1 12.08.2011 10`
`aaa aaaa 1 13.08.2011 8`
`aaa aaaa 1 14.08.2011 7`
And i need result like this:
`name | surname | project | dates | hours | dates | hours | dates | hours | total`
`aaa aaaa 1 12.08.2011 10 13.08.2011 8 14.08.2011 7 25`

`SELECT name,surname,project`,
`MAX(DECODE(C,1,dates)) dates,`
`MAX(DECODE(C,1,hours)) hours,`
`MAX(DECODE(C,2,dates)) dates,`
`MAX(DECODE(C,2,hours)) hours,`
`MAX(DECODE(C,3,dates)) dates,`
`MAX(DECODE(C,3,hours)) hours,`
`sum(hours) as Total`
`FROM (SELECT name,surname,project,dates,hours
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY project ORDER BY project) C
FROM work )
GROUP BY name,surname,project`
This work. But I need dynamically sql query because number of rows can be variable. Is it possible ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the sql dynamically. Look into the DBMS_SQL package. But each row needs to have the same number of columns.

Another way to do this is to return a nested table or vararray of dates and hours.